# how can we remove relative path for images from an angular4 project?

Tags: angular, svg, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am working on Angular 4 project when ever i work in development environment relative path works fine but when we deploy our project it on test machine it does not find images path because in deployment server we have an extra directory.

For example our localhost url looks like below

```
http://localhost:10000/login
```

For test environment url look like below

```
http://servername:10000/projectname/login
```

Both url works fine and point to a login page if we use images through CSS it works see below.

```
icon-design {
    background-image: url('@{images}/indicator.svg');
}
```

Now I have actual problem that I have some drawing component which uses SVG internally and accept images through URL if we give image url as relative path it works for localhost like below

```
"../../../assets/img/1.png"
```

But same relative path does not work with test environment as test server url is little bit diffrent see above for URL?

Can any let me know how can we solve this issue?

Comment: Had the same issue, change it to ./assets/img...

Comment: Thanks a lot. it work for me but i do not understand logic behind it. Can you please let me know why this works?

Comment: When you are using /path you are assuming your path start at the root "level", in general, it's not true. Many servers providers will not give you a direct access to / but your web app will be in /www or even /home/webProject (can be anything) . When you use ./ you start at the project "level" which is ./src for an angular project, inside you have assets that can be accessed directly. Last thing for other imports, I recommand you to find them using ./directory.... instead of /app/.../directory  as you did in the example. For image it works because your base href="./"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than "/assets/img", use "./assets/img" to get relative URLs.